Understand the Lorentz transformation in QFT
I am a beginner in QFT,so let me introduce my question by the problem in MIT8.323 (2023 spring,by Hong Liu) pset 1
.

All steps seem clear, the measure is invariant because the Jacobian is 1 and the contraction $p^\mu x_\mu$ is invariant.
But now let's consider another point of view. Now we treat the $\delta$ function as the integral on $(R^4,\eta)$,and the Lorentz transformation is a coordinate transformation on $R^4$,so this integral is invariant.
But there is a subtlety,because when we prove a integral on a manifold is independent to the choice of coordinate chart $\phi$,we need to introduce the pullback of the form $\omega$,i.e. we have $\int_{\phi(U)} (\phi^{-1})^*(\omega)$ is invariant. but in this problem we don't use the pullback of a Lorentz transformation,how this happens?Are they the same thing?
EDIT:to make my question more clear.Let's consider a form $\omega =f(x^1,x^2)dx^1 \wedge dx^2$.Now we do a coordiante transformation $x$ to $y(x)$,then is it correct that the form become $$f(x^1(y^i),x^2(y^j)) \det {M }\space dy^1 \wedge dy^2=g(y^1,y^2) \det {M}\space dy^1 \wedge dy^2$$
And then the change of integral domain denotes a $\det M^{-1}$ so the integral remains the same.
In this question,why $p$ also changes into $\Lambda p$?Physically its obivous,but how this holds mathematically?

A Lorentz transformation from coordinates $x^i$ to $y^i$ has components $\Lambda^i_{\ j} = \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}$. Its pullback on the volume form $\mathrm d^4x \equiv \mathrm dx^{0}\wedge\mathrm dx^{1}\wedge\mathrm dx^{2}\wedge\mathrm dx^{3}$ is equivalent to the tensor transformation law:
$$\mathrm dx^{0}\wedge\mathrm dx^{1}\wedge\mathrm dx^{2}\wedge\mathrm dx^{3} = \frac{\partial y^{0}}{\partial x^{j_0}}\frac{\partial y^{1}}{\partial x^{j_1}}\frac{\partial y^{2}}{\partial x^{j_2}}\frac{\partial y^{3}}{\partial x^{j_3}} \mathrm dy^{j_0}\wedge\mathrm dy^{j_1}\wedge\mathrm dy^{j_2}\wedge\mathrm dy^{j_3}$$
Although the RHS sums over all combinations of $j_0,j_1,j_2,j_3$, the wedge product is anticommutative and so only terms with the $j$'s all unique survive. Furthermore the anticommutative property can be used along with the Levi-Civita symbol to express the RHS in terms of $\mathrm dy^{0}\wedge\mathrm dy^{1}\wedge\mathrm dy^{2}\wedge\mathrm dy^{3} \equiv \mathrm d^4y$:
$$\mathrm d^4x = \epsilon^{j_0j_1j_2j_3}\frac{\partial y^{0}}{\partial x^{j_0}}\frac{\partial y^{1}}{\partial x^{j_1}}\frac{\partial y^{2}}{\partial x^{j_2}}\frac{\partial y^{3}}{\partial x^{j_3}}\mathrm d^4y$$
Where $\epsilon^{j_0j_1j_2j_3}$ are the components of the $4$-dimensional Levi-Civita symbol.
The coefficient of $\mathrm d^4y$ is the component-wise definition of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix,
$$\mathrm d^4x = \det(\Lambda)\mathrm d^4y$$
Therefore showing the Jacobian is $1$ is equivalent to showing that the volume form is invariant under pullback by a Lorentz transformation.
Edit:
The change of variables from $x$ to $\tilde x = \Lambda x$ does not change $p$ in the exponential at all, it changes the variable being integrated over and parameterizes $x$ in terms of $\tilde x$:
$$\frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{ip\cdot x}\mathrm d^4x = \frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{ip\cdot x(\tilde x)}\det(\Lambda)\mathrm d^4\tilde x$$
As an entirely separate operation, $\Lambda$ can be inserted into the dot product because a Lorentz transformation is an orthogonal transformation:
$$(\Lambda p)\cdot(\Lambda x) = p\cdot x$$
There is no physical intuition or reasoning required for this step, it is the definition of an orthogonal transformation (the above equation holds for any 2 vectors, not just position $x$ and momentum $p$).
Then (with $\det(\Lambda) = 1)$ we have
$$\frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{ip\cdot x}\mathrm d^4x = \frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{i(\Lambda p)\cdot (\Lambda x)}\mathrm d^4\tilde x$$
Then $\Lambda x$ can be replaced with $\tilde x$, $(\Lambda p)\cdot(\Lambda x) = (\Lambda p)\cdot \tilde x$:
$$\frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{ip\cdot x}\mathrm d^4x = \frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{i(\Lambda p)\cdot \tilde x}\mathrm d^4\tilde x$$
Since $\tilde x$ is being integrated over it can be relabeled freely without changing the value of the integral, so we can change it as $\tilde x\to x$ to clarify the comparison of the LHS and the RHS:
$$\frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{ip\cdot x}\mathrm d^4x = \frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{i(\Lambda p)\cdot x}\mathrm d^4x$$
Finally, if we have $\delta^4(p) = \frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{ip\cdot x}\mathrm d^4x$ then we have $\delta^4(\Lambda p) = \frac1{(2\pi)^4}\int e^{i(\Lambda p)\cdot x}\mathrm d^4x$ and therefore with the above equality,
$$\delta^4(p) = \delta^4(\Lambda p)$$
Hopefully this clarifies the derivation and how $\Lambda$ ended up on $p$.

Thank you for your answering.But I am still a bit confused about this.I can see the volume form is invariant indeed,but how the coefficient of the 4-form,which is $Exp(i p^\mu x_\mu)$ in this problem, is acted by $\Lambda$?

The inner product $p\cdot x$ is invariant under a Lorentz transformation of $x$ and $p$, $p\cdot x = (\Lambda p)\cdot(\Lambda x)$ (This is one of the main defining properties of a Lorentz transformation), then defining $\tilde x \equiv \Lambda x$ gives $p\cdot x = (\Lambda p)\cdot \tilde x$ and hence $e^{ip\cdot x} = e^{i(\Lambda p)\cdot \tilde x}$

I just edited my question in detail,I can understand your answering physically,but how this works mathematically?

@MakiseKurisu I extended my answer to try and address your edit

Thank you for your answering again.Now I can grasp your idea but still not sure why $px(x')=\Lambda p\space \Lambda x$

@MakiseKurisu The dot product expressed in terms of column vectors and matrices is $p\cdot x = p^T\eta x$, where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric. As stated in the problem set, a Lorentz transformation preserves the metric: $\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda = \eta$. This implies that the dot product is invariant if both vectors are transformed by $\Lambda$: $(\Lambda p)\cdot(\Lambda x) = (\Lambda p)^T\eta(\Lambda x) = p^T\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda x = p^T(\Lambda^T\eta\Lambda)x = p^T\eta x = p\cdot x$. Let me know if its still unclear.

I want to propose a different approach, as I believe the OP might benefit from comparing different viewpoints on distribution theory.
The question is really about the transformation of distributions under changes of variables. Notice that you want to phrase your question for Minkowski space instead of a more general smooth manifold. The reason is that only in Minkowski space Lorentz transformations act as coordinate transformations, while on more general manifolds they act locally instead, on each tangent space.
That said let us start with the following definitions:

Definition: Let $C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be the space of compactly supported smooth functions. The space of continuous linear functionals $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is called the space of distributions and an element $\zeta\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is called a regular distribution when there exists a corresponding $f\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $$\langle \zeta,\phi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} d^d x \ f(x)\phi(x)\tag{1}.$$

The Dirac delta is nothing but the evaluation functional: $$\langle \delta,\phi\rangle = \phi(0)\tag{2}$$
and it is a well-known fact that it is not a regular distribution (there is no function against which we integrate $\phi$ to generate the action (2)). That said, imagine $\zeta$ is regular. Let us understand what changes of variables to do it. If $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a diffeomorphism (smooth bijective map with smooth inverse), then a function transform as $$f\mapsto \Phi^\ast f = f\circ \Phi\tag{3}. $$
Let us define $\Phi^\ast \zeta$ to be the regular distribution determined by $\Phi^\ast f$. Then $$\langle \Phi^\ast \zeta,\phi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} d^d x \Phi^\ast f(x)\phi(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx f(\Phi(x))\phi(x)\tag{4}.$$
Now change variables on the integral by putting $x = \Phi^{-1}(y)$. The change of variables theorem will imply you pick up a jacobian and we get
$$\langle \Phi^\ast \zeta,\phi\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dy f(y)|J^{-1}|\phi(\Phi^{-1}(y)),\quad J^{-1} = \det\dfrac{\partial \Phi^{-1}}{\partial y}\tag{5}$$
But now we recognize the action of $\zeta$ again. This means we propose the following definition for the composition of a distribution with a function

Let $\zeta\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be a distribution and $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ a diffeomorphism, we define $\Phi^\ast \zeta$ to be the distribution:
$$(\Phi^\ast\zeta, \phi)=(\zeta, |J^{-1}|\phi\circ \Phi^{-1}),\tag{6}$$
where $J^{-1}$ is the jacobian of the inverse transformation $\Phi^{-1}$.

The idea is simply that we took the behavior of regular distributions and extrapolated it to all distributions. Now take the Dirac delta. We will have
$$\langle \Phi^\ast \delta,\phi\rangle = \langle\delta,|J^{-1}|\phi\circ \Phi^{-1}\rangle = |J^{-1}(0)|\phi(\Phi^{-1}(0)).\tag{7}$$
Now assume $\Phi$ to be linear, write $x = x^\mu e_\mu$ and assume $\Phi e_\mu = \Lambda^\nu_{\phantom\nu\mu}e_\nu$. In that case we have that $\Phi^{-1} e_\mu = (\Lambda^{-1})^\nu_{\phantom\nu\mu}e_\nu$. This means that $J^{-1} = \det \Lambda^{-1}$. Moreover, linearity of $\Phi$ implies $\Phi(0)=\Phi^{-1}(0)=0$. As such for linear maps
$$\langle \Phi^\ast \delta,\phi\rangle = \langle\delta,|J^{-1}|\phi\circ \Phi^{-1}\rangle = |\det\Lambda^{-1}|\phi(0) = |\det\Lambda^{-1}|\langle \delta,\phi\rangle.\tag{8}$$
Hence follows the equality of distributions $$\Phi^\ast \delta = |\det\Lambda^{-1}|\delta,\quad \delta(\Lambda x) = |\det\Lambda^{-1}| \delta(x),\tag{9}$$
where in the right I used the Physicist notation. When $\Lambda\in {\rm SO}(p,q)$ is a Lorentz transformation (assuming $\mathbb{R}^d$ endowed with the flat metric of signature $p+q=d$), we have $\det\Lambda^{-1}=\pm 1$ and hence $$\delta(\Lambda x)=\delta(x).\tag{10}$$
